# Passing Variable through Notification to Activity

Tags: android, notifications

Here is the code that I have:

**GCMIntentService:**

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.putExtra("screen", activityToShow);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIconToDisplayInGCM)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIconToDisplayInGCM)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setSound(sound)
        .setTicker(ticker)
        .setContentIntent(intent2)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Main Activity:

onCreate()

```
onNewIntent(getIntent())
```

New Method outside of onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String tabNumber = "";

    if(extras != null) {
        tabNumber = extras.getString("screen");
        Log.d("TEMP", "Tab Number: " + tabNumber);
        if(tabNumber.equals("") || (tabNumber == null)) {
            // Set the active tab to be the Home Tab  (index = 0)
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        } else {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(getTabToShow(tabNumber));
        }
    } else {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

It's not even hitting the Log.d() when I click on the Push Notification.

Answer (score 10):

I've implemented your code with slight modifications to make some debugging:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("screen", "debugScreen"); 
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = 
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Some Title")
            .setContentText("Some text")
            .setContentIntent(intent2)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    nMgr.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
```

And the onNewIntent method:

```
@Override 
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){ 
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
    String tabNumber;

    if(extras != null) {
        tabNumber = extras.getString("screen");
        Log.d("TEMP", "Tab Number: " + tabNumber);

    } else {
        Log.d("TEMP", "Extras are NULL");

    }
}
```

I could check it works fine and the variable gets passed to the activity in the intent.

What I think you might be doing wrong is setting the intent data with the variable **activityToShow**. Take into account that *Intent.putExtra(...)* is an overloaded method, and if you pass, for instance, an Integer, you won't be able to get a String.

I recommend you to monitor the state of the **activityToShow** variable, and add some logging to the receiver, to check what you get (including the variable type) and what you receive in the activity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: where i called onNewIntent() method

Comment: in your Activity - `MainActivity.java`